# PageAdapter is not outputting normal datas

Tags: java, android, adapter

I am still learning and trying to implement PageAdapter and i dont understand some things.

```
public class Card
{
    public Card(final Context iContext, final Class<?> iNextActivity, int iDrawable)
    {
        drawable = iDrawable;
        onClick = new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                //this just opens an activity using Intent
                ActivityManipulator.openActivity(iContext, iNextActivity); 
            }
        };
    }
    public View.OnClickListener onClick;
    public int drawable;
}


public class InfiniteCycleViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public InfiniteCycleViewPagerAdapter(Context iContext, List<Card> iCards)
    {
        cards = iCards;
        context = iContext;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(iContext);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cards.size();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position)
    {
        Log.d("instantiateItem", Integer.toString(position));
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Card card = cards.get(position);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(card.onClick);
        imageView.setImageResource(card.drawable);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    List<Card> cards;
}
```

**initialization:**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        cards.add(new Card(this, ActivityProductList.class, R.drawable.product));
        cards.add(new Card(this, ActivityEmployeeList.class, R.drawable.employee));
        cards.add(new Card(this, ActivityCustomerList.class, R.drawable.customer));

        HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.cycle);

        pager.setAdapter(new InfiniteCycleViewPagerAdapter(this, cards));

        Log.d("dashboard::oncreate", "dashboard");
    }

}
```

1. as you can see I have 3 cards fed to the `PageAdapter` object, why is my `Log.d("instantiateItem", Integer.toString(position));` outputs this:

`instantiateItem: 0
    instantiateItem: 2
    instantiateItem: 1
    instantiateItem: 1
    instantiateItem: 2`

I dont understand why its 02112 and why it is called 5 times?

2. Why is `Log.d("dashboard::oncreate", "dashboard");` called before the instantiateItem method in my InfiniteCycleViewPagerAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you see multiple calls to `instantiateItem` is most probably related to the internal implementation of `HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager`.

I would take a guess and speculate that it probably instantiates the current "page", and extrapolates other "pages" to both "directions". This way you'll land on page 1 if you swipe left and page 2 if you swipe right.

You see a call to `Log.d("dashboard::oncreate", "dashboard");` before `instantiateItem` because Android UI thread uses so-called `Looper` (looper threads are very common approach to GUI implementation).

What happens is approximately the following:

1. `onCreate` is run by UI `Looper` on UI thread
2. during `onCreate`, a call to `pager.setAdapter(new InfiniteCycleViewPagerAdapter(this, cards))` takes place
3. somewhere inside your `ViewPager` there is call that handles initialization. This call is not a direct method call, but addition of "initialization" `Runnable` object to UI `Looper` (the mechanism that adds `Runnables` is called `Handler`)
4. "initialization" `Runnable` is waiting inside UI `Looper` for all other work that was added prior to it to complete. This work includes the aforementioned call to `onCreate`
5. once all other work on UI `Looper` completed, "initialization" `Runnable` is run on UI thread

If you'd like to dig deeper into `Looper`, `Handler` and event thread I recommend [this YouTube video by Douglas Schmidt](https://youtu.be/S1Y1Zt3lfeQ).

Comment: sorry for late. Ive researched everything you said I understand now thanks !